# C++ How to allow copy-list-initialization for a perfect forwarding function?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution, perfect-forwarding

Suppose I have a perfect forwarding function:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T&& t) { /* does something */ }
```

I have some types `T` that I want to allow Copy-list-initialization for, say they are `std::pair<int, int>` and `std::tuple<int, int, int>`:

```cpp
f({1, 2}); // I want to do this
f({1, 2, 3}); // and I also want to do this

f(std::pair{1, 2}); // instead of this
```

I know that I have to have an overload of `f(const std::pair<int, int>&)` for this. How do I call `f(T&&)` inside `f(const std::pair<int, int>&)`?

```cpp
void f(const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    f(p); // How do I make this resolve to f(T&&)?
}
```

Comment: it appears you didnt ask the question you actually wanted to ask. No problem. You can open a new question to ask for pair and tuple and to exclude solutions you already have in mind but rule out for some reasons. Consider that the answers already given address the question as it stands now, hence changing the question to ask for something else will invalidate those answers. If you do edit, you should ping the answers so they can be updated.

Comment: oh, I was late to the party :D you already made the changes. Please in such case inform the answers. And next time consider to open a new question. The answers you got were fine for the question you initially asked

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for sounding impolite earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

```cpp
void f(const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    f<const std::pair<int, int>&>(p);
}
```

Edit: Or slightly better:

```cpp
void f(const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
    f<decltype(p)>(p);
}
```